# Copy file into directories, and change text inside file to match index of directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following files in a directory: `text.txt` and `text2.txt`
My goal is to:

1) copy these two files into non-existing directories `m06/`, `m07/`...`m20/`.

2) Then, in the file `text.txt`, in the line containing the string `mlist 06` (all the files will contain such a string), I wish to change the "06" to match the index of the directory name (for example, in `m13`, that line in the `text.txt` file would be `mlist 13`.

For goal 1), I got the following script which works succesfully:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $(printf "m%02i " $(seq 6 20))
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'm[0-9][0-9]' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp text.txt {}
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'm[0-9][0-9]' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp text2.txt {}
```

For goal 2), I wish to implement a command similar to

```
sed -i -e '/mlist/s/06/index/' ./*/text.inp
```

where `index` would correspond to the name of the directory (i.e. index = 13 in the `m13/`directory).

How can I make the `sed` command replace `06` with the correct "index" corresponding to the name of the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be easier to manage if you used loop syntax instead of one-liners:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 6 20); do
    # Add a leading 0 and generate the directory name
    i_z=$(printf "%02d" "$i")
    dir="m${i_z}"

    # Create dir
    mkdir -p "$dir"

    # Copy base files into dir
    cp test.txt test2.txt "$dir"

    # Edit the index in the files to match the dir index
    sed -i -e "s/mlist.*/mlist $i_z/g" \
        "${dir}/test.txt" "${dir}/test2.txt"
done
```

Comment: Great... though on top of having `test.txt` and `test2.txt` in each dir, there are files called `test.txt-e` and `test2.txt-e` as well. They are unmodified. Where do they come from?

Comment: @JanRostenkowski I believe they're "bread-crumb" leftovers of using ```sed -i``` that creates backup files... try using ```--in-place``` instead of plain ```-i```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Running the script above as-is does not result in those files on my machine. You might try removing the `-e` argument from the `sed` command... it should work fine without it and maybe your version of `sed` differs from mine.

Comment: BSD sed's -i is different from that of GNU sed, former takes exactly one argument and uses it as the backup suffix. `sed -i '' -e ...` wouldn't create those files